# Allow direct IP access

Tags: discussion, feature-request, outage, dns

The recent [DNS outage](//wired.com/2016/10/internet-outage-ddos-dns-dyn) caused me to lose access to the Stack Exchange
network. Being a good little programmer, I tried to work around the problem:

```
$ wget --spider stackoverflow.com
Connecting to stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)|151.101.1.69|:80... connected.
```

So currently for me Stack Overflow is 151.101.1.69. However Stack Exchange does
not allow direct IP access:

> Fastly error: unknown domain: 151.101.1.69. Please check that this domain has
>   been added to a service.

This is also true for Super User and perhaps others. I would like to see this
corrected, as other major sites like Google, GitHub and Facebook do allow direct
IP access.

Comment: We only have four IP addresses that service *all* of our sites. How is it supposed to know which site you're actually wanting to access?

Comment: @animuson In theory, you should be able to send a HTTP request directly to the IP (bypassing DNS), but by including a `Host:` header, the servers can recognize which site you're accessing. That's exactly the issue that HTTP/1.1 was created to work around - if Fastly allows you to, then "which site do you want" isn't an issue for direct IP access.

Comment: Confirmed - you can do direct IP access by including the Host header: run `curl -H "Host: stackoverflow.com" 151.101.129.69` to verify that.

Comment: Incidentally, you can locally bypass DNS for a domain name by editing your `/etc/hosts` file and adding a static rule (among other similar options).